# Spotfire custom expression to calculate the sum of median values

Tags: spotfire

I am working on a Spotfire cost estimation tool based on past unit costs.  The units are made of multiple different parts that are grouped into different cost codes.

The first part is easy, I have simply made a cross table based on cost code and median cost and summed added in the sum total at the bottom of the cross table.

screen shot of current cross table

[image: screen shot of current cross table]

This is where I need help: I need to use that sum of the median values in other parts of my spotfire guide for further calculations such as normalization, and to put into an auto generating text field for the write up.

A coworker recommended: Median([Cost]) then Sum([Value]) over (All([Axis.Rows]))

cross table with  Median([Cost]) then Sum([Value]) over (All([Axis.Rows]))

[image: cross table with Median([Cost]) then Sum([Value]) over (All([Axis.Rows]))]

This does create the sum that I'm looking for, but it only works in a cross table that is partitioned by the cost codes.  I need to be able to calculate that value completely separate from the cost code table.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly you want to capture the total and use in other places:

You can use a data function to capture an expression from your datatable and save to a document property. That way the value of the document property will be available in other parts of the analysis.

[image]

Comment: Tyger, thank you for the help.

I am not just trying to use the sum of the column, but the sum of median values from a cross table since there are multiple "Unit IDs" that are feeding into it.  Will your solution work in that case?
Also, I haven't been looking for the edit script menus that you show, but haven't been able to find them.  What is the path to access them?
Thank you again

Comment: You can set any expression : so just swap out the Sum() calculation with the same expression your using in your cross table. And you can create a new function from Data->Data Functions->Register New and alter the parameters from Data->Data Functions->Edit Parameters

Comment: As a suggestion : I would create this same question on https://community.tibco.com/answers and include a sample dxp. It's sometimes hard to translate a need without the underlying data table and complete use case

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question posed in a comment on Tyger's answer (sorry im new not enough rep to comment there):

You can add a new data function via menu bar / data / data functions / register new. The help content is decent on this topic as well.